# Is it possible to force the left hand side of an `=` to fully evaluate to a reference before the right hand side is evaluated?

Tags: javascript

To expand on the question, I want this statement to be possible:

```
declare("Hello") = bindVal("World")
```

where both `declare` and `bindVal` are functions that does something like this:

```
function declare(p){ return window[p] }
function bindVal(x){ return x }
```

The point here is that `declare` runs some operation and has some side effects. But in my case declare doesn't have to return anything. Though if it return a "dangling" variable waiting to be assigned a value, that would be most ideal.

Now running this expression in the console throws the error:

```
ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

So my question is : can I do anything fancy with function `declare` such that my statement is possible? In my mind, this is the sequence of how the left and right hand side to be evaluated:

```
declare("Hello") = bindVal("world")
window.Hello     = bindVal("world")
window.Hello     = world
```

In summary, the left hand side fully evaluates before the right hand side.

Comment: It is impossible to assign a value to a function call.

Comment: I don't get the question. Why cannot you just write `window.Hello     = world`?

Comment: You should put the assignment inside of `declare` and pass `bindVal(...)` as a second parameter.

Comment: In reality, there would be a lot more going on inside declare and bindVal than variable assignment. But all the other stuff is stripped off to show the crux of what's going on.

Comment: In your example sequence, `declare` doesn't return `window.Hello`.  It returns `"promise"`, so the last line would be `"promise" = "world"` which is clearly nonsense to the interpreter.

Comment: Yeah oops, fixed it so it returns undefined which is also senseless I'm guessing. the point is that I want a function to return a reference but don't know how to do that, so what ever logic I have inside `declare` is wrong.

Comment: @chibro2 As I wrote in my answer, a function **can't return a reference**.

Comment: Yes, your logic is wrong, and as @dystroy points out, it can't ever be made right.  Functions return fully evaluated values.  If it's something you can return from a function, it's by definition *not* something you can assign to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The left part of [an assignment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1) [must be a reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.2) and [you can't return a reference from a function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7) :

> No built-in ECMAScript function defined by this specification returns
>   a reference and there is no provision for a user-defined function to
>   return a reference.

So you have to do it otherwise.

You could return the name of the variable to change but the cleanest would be to return a function doing the assignment :

```
function declare(n){
   return function(v){ window[n]=v }
}
declare("Hello")(bindVal("World"));
```

Comment: Is it possible for a function to lookup the name of its reference? So this function `name = function(){ return findMyName() }` would return `name`

Comment: Well, what would it do in `name1 = name2 = function(){ return findMyName() }` ?

Comment: So is it possible if I ignore that use case, and only focus on non-aliased assignments?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how variable work in JS. The link is from the variable to the value, not the reverse.

Comment: Is it possible attach a reference "local" scope? So for example in this case : `window.a = 12`, I'm scoping `a` to `window`, and can be accessed later by calling `window.a`. Is it possible to do something like `local.a = 13` such that by just calling `a`, I get 13?

Comment: @chibro2 There is the infamous [with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) keyword. Don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do sounds very interesting, but unfortunately with Javascript you cannot do that.

`declare` a function can only do operations and return something or nothing.

You cannot assign anything to a function execution call, you can however try something like chaining methods in javascript.